# Pythonのurllib.request.Requestでheadersを指定しても反映されない?

Tags: python, python3

Python3の`urllib.request.Request`のheadersでhttp headerを指定してもheaderが送信されないのですがなぜこのようなことがおこるのでしょうか?

mnctf2017というctfサイトの情報照会というお題に取り組んでいるのですが、この問題では、FLAGをとるためにAPIサーバに問い合わせる必要があります。
APIにアクセスするためにはAPI tokenのようなものを`X-TOKEN`ヘッダに追加しなければなりません。
X-TOKENヘッダを追加するためにurllib.request.Requestの引数のheadersに`{"X-TOKEN": token}`としてリクエストを送信するのですが、X-TOKENをヘッダに追加したにもかかわらず、X-TOKENがないというエラーが返ってきます。

なぜでしょうか?

ちなみに他の方の答えを見たところrequestsをつかうとうまくいくようです。

urllibを使ってアクセスするコード:

```
import urllib.request as ur
import urllib.parse as up
import time
import json

hashlist = open("minhashlist.txt").read().split("\n")[:-1]
malware_name = "RAT.A.aa74e"
apikey = "578459a056231ac6745fcb53e3304b3043bb7c9448863e84652764592d15b3d1"

def get_apitoken():
    post_data = up.urlencode({"key": apikey}).encode("utf-8")
    res = ur.urlopen("http://157.7.53.197/intel/gettoken/", data=post_data)
    res_str = res.read().decode("ascii")
    res_json = json.loads(res_str)
    return res_json["expire"], res_json["token"]

def search(token, hash):
    print(token)
    data = up.urlencode({"hash": hash}).encode("utf-8")
    req = ur.Request("http://157.7.53.197/intel/query/", data=data, headers={
        "x-token": token # ここで"X-TOKEN"を追加した
        })
    res = ur.urlopen(req)
    body = res.read().decode("utf-8")
    res_json = json.loads(body)
    if res_json["auth"] != "success": #認証に失敗したらエラーを発生させる
        raise Exception("auth error: " + res_json["reason"])
    if malware_name in detection_name:
        print("answer:", res_json["hash"])

def main():
    expire, token = get_apitoken()
    expire = int(expire)
    for v in hashlist:
        search(token, v)
        now = time.time()
        if now >= expired:
            expire, token = get_apitoken()
            expire = int(expire)
```

エラーメッセージ:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getinfo.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()
  File "getinfo.py", line 35, in main
    search(token, v)
  File "getinfo.py", line 27, in search
    raise Exception("auth error: " + res_json["reason"])
Exception: auth error: no x-token header
```

http://mnctf.info/mnctf2017/top.php
[上のURLの"情報照会"という問題です]

このCTFで使用するAPIサーバの仕様書
http://mnctf.info/mnctf2017/task/MiNTEL_API_Reference.pdf

環境: 
Windows 10
Python 3.6.7

Comment: 小文字ではなく、仕様書通り大文字でもだめですか？tokenは取得できていますか？

Comment: @flied onion 大文字でも同じエラーが出ます。
Tokenは取得できています。

Comment: [ここ](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/urllib/request.py#L407)を見ますと、HTTP header のタグは capitalize されてしまいますので、`X-TOKEN` は `X-token` に置き換えられてしまいますね。

Comment: 追加情報ですが、[ここ](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/urllib/request.py#L1302)でも `title()` メソッドを使ってタグを書き替えています。前述の capitalize の部分は、`req.headers.update({'X-TOKEN': token})` とでもすれば回避できますが、こちらは、、、継承クラスを作って `do_open()` メソッドをオーバーライドすれば良いかもしれませんけれども、煩雑になりますね。。。

Comment: http header の仕様上は、header の各フィールド名は case insensitive なので、サーバ側の不具合とも言えそうです。（https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http.serverとsocketserverでKiYugadgeterさんと、ネットで見かけた同じ問題をrequestsで解いていたコードのPOSTヘッダを見比べてみましたがたしかにX-TOKENも送信されてましたし、差はConnectionくらいでしたね。

と、思ったんですが、urllibでは`X-TOKEN`が `X-Token`にされていますね。
（修正） これが原因だったようです。追記を参照してください。

```
import urllib.request as ur
import urllib.parse as up
import requests

def query(hash, token):
  # 参考用
  r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/', headers={
    'X-TOKEN': token
  }, data={
    'hash': hash
  })
  return r.json()

def search(token, hash):
    print(token)
    data = up.urlencode({"hash": hash}).encode("utf-8")
    req = ur.Request("http://127.0.0.1:8000/", data=data, headers={
        "X-TOKEN": token # ここで"X-TOKEN"を追加した
        })
    res = ur.urlopen(req)
    body = res.read().decode("utf-8")

search('a', 'h')
# 参考用
query('h2', 'a2')
```

urllib

```
Accept-Encoding: identity
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 6
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
User-Agent: Python-urllib/3.6
X-Token: a
Connection: close
```

requests

```
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
User-Agent: python-requests/2.18.4
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
X-TOKEN: a2
Content-Length: 7
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

参考にさせていただいたサイト：
https://st98.github.io/diary/posts/2017-07-10-mnctf-2017.html

python 3.6.4 (Anaconda)

---

追記：

参考のrequestsを使ったコードで、`X-Token`にして送信実行してみたところ、
`no x-token header`エラーが返されましたので、urllibが小文字にしてしまうのが原因のようです。
（最後まではやっていませんが、`X-TOKEN`の場合はしばらく動作してました。）

HTTPヘッダの仕様ではcase-insensitiveであるべきだったと思いますが、サーバープログラムの都合でしょうね。
urllibだと別の文字クラスを用意するような結構手間なようなので、requestsを使うのが現実的かもしれません。

上記の「別の文字クラスを・・・」は以下のstackoverflowの回答を参考にしました。

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18268226/2513010

Answer (score 0):

python 3.7 ですが、httpbin を使って確認したところ、"X-Token"ヘッダーは送信されていました。サーバ仕様の理解に認識違いがあったりはしませんか？

ソースコード

```
import urllib.request as ur

req = ur.Request("https://httpbin.org/post", data=b"foo", headers={"x-token": "token"})
res = ur.urlopen(req)
body = res.read().decode("utf-8")
print(body)
```

出力結果

```
$ python3.7 request.py                                                                                                                                        
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {
    "foo": ""
  },
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Length": "3",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "Python-urllib/3.7",
    "X-Token": "token"
  },
  "json": null,
  "origin": "133.200.138.64",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```